# What directory is '~' when I type 'cd ~'?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, command-line

I'm only new to using SSH, but when I log in I end up in the directory ~, which in general is the same directory when FTPing in. I can still go to /, but I don't know what the ~ means. Home? Where is it in relation to /, or how could I find out?

Comment: (How) Is this question programming related? (Trying to find out what kind of questions are accepted on stackoverflow...)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

~ is an alias to the currently logged in users home directory.  To find out where that really is, type `pwd` (stands for: Print Working Directory) **right after logging in**, which should give you the location relative to `/`.  It's probably something like:

```
/home/myusername
```

Comment: Your profile chain can quite easily change your current working directory before the prompt appears. A more reliable way is "( cd ; pwd )" to, in a subshell, change to your home directory then print out the working directory.

Comment: Actually, that's not true either, since the .bashrc runs for each subshell as well (hence can change directory). Even $HOME can be modified :-). Safest is to check your entry in /etc/passwd.

Comment: ~ is always whatever $HOME is set to, so ctrl's suggestion of "echo ~" will work, as will "echo $HOME" or "cd;pwd" (since cd defaults to changing to $HOME).  You shouldn't second-guess yourself, pax. :)

Comment: Checking /etc/passwd would work only if your system really *uses* /etc/passwd - which is may not be the case for LDAP-based auth, for example...

Answer (score 8):

~ is your home directory, yes. Which is very nice since your home directory is not always where you think it should be (/home/).

Also, fun fact: You can use "cd ~myuser" to get to the home directory of the user "myuser".

Comment: One time it won't be where you "think" it should be is on OS X - "~" expands to "/Users/myuser" rather than "/home/myuser". It's nice to use "~" so us OS X users can still get the same functionality!

Comment: Older Unix systems often didn't have a /home directory, so the home directories were under something like /usr/users.  Using "~" works for them, too.

Answer (score 7):

As others have commented, the tilde indicates your current `$HOME` directory.  This may or may not be the same as the value of `~username` for your user name.  On my machine, `$HOME` and `~` both refer to `/work1/jleffler`.  However, `~jleffler` is a reference to an NFS mounted directory, `/u/jleffler`, as specified in the `/etc/passwd` file (or any equivalent database - the POSIX standard defines the behaviour in terms of the `getpwnam()` function; see below). My profile carefully sets `$HOME`.  It is interesting (aka exasperating) to work out which software packages use the wrong definition of the home directory.

For most people, `~` and `~username` are the same for their user name, but that is not required.  Given that you are asking the question, it is almost certainly the case that `~` and `~username` are the same.

Quote from section 2.6.1 'Tilde Expansion' of POSIX.1-2008:

> A "tilde-prefix" consists of an unquoted `<tilde>` character at the beginning of a word, followed by all of the characters preceding the first unquoted `<slash>` in the word, or all the characters in the word if there is no `<slash>`. [...] If the login name is null (that is, the tilde-prefix contains only the tilde), the tilde-prefix is replaced by the value of the variable HOME. If HOME is unset, the results are unspecified.  Otherwise, the tilde-prefix shall be replaced by a pathname of the initial working directory associated with the login name obtained using the `getpwnam()` function [...]. If the system does not recognize the login name, the results are undefined.

Comment: How strange this is the post that talks about /etc/passwd and ~, but it is not the accepted answer.

Comment: Got there an hour too late :D

Answer (score 4):

You can try [realpath](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/en/man1/realpath.1.html)

```
realpath ~
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is the home directory of the user you logged in as.  You can use the command `pwd` (print working directory) to see where it is located on the file system.

Answer (score 2):

~ expands to your home directory, as has been pointed out, but I think it's worth noting that isn't a feature of ssh itself.

ssh (among many other wonderful features!) lets you establish a remote *shell*, and this shell can provided by many different pieces of software.

On a *nix system, your account will be associated with a particular shell, [GNU bash](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_toc.html#SEC_Contents) is a popular choice. And it so happens than in bash, and most other POSIX compliant shells, the [tilde character expands as a shortcut to your home directory](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_28.html).

Answer (score 1):

/ is the root of the file system
~/ or ~ is the root of your profile, ~/ is always /home/username

Comment: It's not always /home/username since you're not forced to have your home directory under /home. I'd suggest clarifying that before you get -1'ed :-)

Comment: And it isn't forced to be the directory listed in the password file.  It just usually is.

Answer (score 1):

Different shells may or may not handle this differently, but Johnathan got the closest without coming out and saying it.  The shell expands "~" to whatever's stored in the $HOME environment variable.  The shell expands ~username to whatever's listed in the shell field of /etc/passwd for the given username.  If you don't override it, the shell (or ssh, depending on the implementation) will set $HOME to be the home field from /etc/passwd, so they're both the same (assuming you're "username") until you change one.

As to why you see a ~ in ssh...

The prompt says "~" is your current directory most likely because you're using Bash as your shell, and the value of $PS1 (the prompt string you see - it's set in /etc/profile or /etc/profile.d/*, more than likely) contains a \w or a \W somewhere.  The \w string in the prompt shows the current directory, and collapses to a "~" when you're in the directory specified by $HOME.  Here's a little demo starting in my homedir - note how the "\w" gets replaced with either the current directory or with a ~, based on what the value of HOME is set to.  Also note that the trailing slash doesn't work - HOME can't end with a slash for this to work. :)

```
danny@machine ~ > export PS1='\w > '     # change my prompt (effective on next line)
~ > cd /tmp                              # move to /tmp to demonstrate
/tmp > export HOME=/tmp/                 # set HOME to include trailing /
/tmp > export HOME=/tmp                  # try again without trailing /
~ >                                      # notice that this works
~ > cd /home/danny                       # back to homedir
/home/danny > export HOME=/home/danny    # see how it's /home/danny, not ~
~ > export PS1='danny@machine \w > '     # after resetting $HOME, it should work ok
danny@machine ~ >                        # hooray!
```

Answer (score 1):

~ is your home directory. To see the path type:

```
echo ~
```

in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

And home, in relation to /, isn't necessarily always in the same place.  That's why the ~ shortcut is so useful.  The path to home should be in $HOME.  Try typing

`echo $HOME`

Answer (score 0):

Home directory need not necessarily be under /home as [kigurai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13565/kigurai) has pointed out.